# Unable to access cPanel direct login URL using iframe

Tags: php, .htaccess, iframe, cpanel

I have admin based created using laravel and there I am trying to open cpanel using iframe code but I am getting the following error:

> Refused to display 'https://demo.cpanel.net:2083/cpsess1054241072/frontend/paper_lantern/index.html?login=1&post_login=44745504761520' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

In the .htaccess file I already tried to add the following rule but with no success:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set X-Frame-Options "allow-from *"
```

Can I get some assistance on it?

Comment: try removing the quotes from `"*"`, not mentioned here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Comment: Also, your second directive is no longer supported in many of todays browsers https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options#Directives

Comment: Use this one instead https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy

Answer (score 0):

They have set the header to `SAMEORIGIN` in your cpanel. 
That means they have disallowed loading of the resource in an iframe outside of their domain.

**Because of that you cant load your cpanel within and ifeame.**

*Please check below image.*

[image: Your Cpanel header]